# How to record multiple tracks with AVFoundation?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I just started learning Swift and wanted to make an app that can record multiple tracks and play them all at once. So far I got this tutorial working: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Recording_Audio_on_iOS_8_with_AVAudioRecorder_in_Swift.

My question is: how can I best modify this to set up 5 tracks to record and play them all at once? My best guess right now is to make 5 urls to record in and make 5 buttons with actions that will call the record() but do I have to make 5 instances of the AVAudioRecorder and AVAudioPlayer?

Thanks!